# emacs-nox 'C-,' & 'C-.' keybindings not working

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I've got a couple emacs keybindings as follows:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-,") 'beginning-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'end-of-buffer)
```

Recently, I realized these don't work in emacs-nox. Is it is possible to get them working, or is this just a limitation of emacs-nox?

Comment: It's probably a limitation of your terminal.  Most terminals I've used don't send any keycodes at all for `C-,` and `C-.`.

Comment: @Spong - You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By popular demand:

It's probably a limitation of your terminal.

Most terminals I've used don't send any keycodes at all for `C-,` and `C-.`.

You can check this by executing `M-x describe-key` (usually bound to `C-h k`), and then typing `C-,` and/or `C-.`.  If Emacs does nothing when you hit the keys, it's your terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it would be something like that. I guess I should just stick with keybindings that will work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

On my emacs(21), `\C-.` and `\C-,` don't register as keyed.  I use terminal through PuTTY.  The default keybindings `\M-<` and `\M->` works fine for me for beginning-of-buffer and end-of-buffer respectively.

So either use the default keys or set some other keys if your emacs-nox does not register them as keyed in.